# MassTransit Saga Configuration For Different Consumer Groups

Tags: apache-kafka, masstransit, saga

I've got a situation where I have 4 input topics in Kafka that I'm trying to write a saga to correlate for me.

Topics **A**, **B** and **C** all contain the structurally same data.  In all cases, I need to correlate the message that comes in on these three topics with a message that comes in on the 4th topic, **D**.  I know that for every entry in **A-C** there will be a record in **D**, but I cannot guarantee that the record will appear on all of these topics.

My plan is to generate 3 sagas ...

- One that correlates **A** and **D** with consumer group **AD**
- One that correlates **B** and **D** with consumer group **BD**
- One that correlates **C** and **D** with consumer group **CD**.

In this way, the message from D will be read three times, but I don't know which of **A-C** it's going to appear on, so I can't wait for a message that may never arrive.

As the only thing that varies here is the name of the topic **A-C** and the name of the consumer group to use, I want to write the saga once and associate it with the structurally identical messages.

I've tried to configure the listener in the `.UsingKafka()` block, but I unclear how I'd do that 3 times.

I've considered that I could create identical (or empty derived) message types for the messages on **A-C** and three different but identical message types that correspond to the message in **D** and then declare the saga as a templated type off of these messages, but that seems very hard-coded.  I figure there needs to be some way to declare this in configuration.  That will require a code change and the creation of a bunch of marker types.

Is there a better way to do this configuration?